# Two constructors having same no. of parameters but different data types

Tags: java, multiple-constructors

Here when I run this below code I get `called` as the output and I was wondering why not `called new`. Since 1 comes under both `short` and `int` range.

```
public class MyClass {

        private int x;

        public MyClass(){
            this(1);
        }

        public MyClass(int x){
            System.out.println("called");
            this.x = x;
        }

       public MyClass(short y){
            System.out.println("called new");
            this.x = y;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`1` is an `int` literal, so `MyClass(int x)` is chosen.

Even if you remove the `MyClass(int x)` constructor, `MyClass(short y)` won't be chosen. You'll get a compilation error instead, since `1` is not `short`.

You'll have to cast `1` to short - `this((short)1);` - in order for the `MyClass(short y)` to be chosen.

Comment: i dont get how 1 is not short

Comment: @Coder17 Any integer numeric literal having no suffix, no matter how small or how large, it considered by the compiler to be an `int`. The compiler doesn't check the value of the `int` literal to determine if it can fit in a `short` variable. The only time the compiler does such a check is when you assign an `int` literal to a `short` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to others answer I can suggest you to check which constructors are being called when you initialize variables of other types using the same literal:

```
short s = 1;
int i = 1;
```

And then check which constructor of `MyClass` is being called as you call them with above arguments.